# Django - Open create/add form with fields precompiled based on other object model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

In my project I use Django admin with Django 1.11, so I have a modelA and a modelB and users can create both of them, but sometimes I need to create a modelA object with some values field based on modelB object.

To do this I have override my /templates/my_app_name/my_modelB/change_form.html template and add a button like this:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
{% block object-tools-items %}

      <div class="form-row form-row-field-quick-view">
            <a href="create_object_A_view">Create ObjA from this ObjB</a>
      </div>
    
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

In this way when I open some ObjB change form I get a link, based on a view whose task is redirect users to the URL /admin/app_name/modelA/add/ and show the proper form with some fields precompiled based on ObjB values which the form came from.
So I created a view like this:

```
class create_object_A_view(View):
    model = ModelA

    url = '/admin/app_name/modelA/add/'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     
       #get data from objB, say it foo and bar....
       form = ModelAForm(initial={'field1': 'foo' , 'field2':'bar'})
    
        return redirect(self.url,
            {'form':form,
            'opts': self.model._meta,
            'change': False,
            'is_popup':False,
            'save_as':False,
            'has_delete_permission':False,
            'has_add_permission': False,
            'has_change_permission':  False})
```

Doing this I get the correct redirect to /admin/app_name/modelA/add/ but the fields that I want to be precompiled are empty.

Is this the proper way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

You can make that happen, by redirecting to the modelA add url with the form data in url itself

for example:

```py
return redirect(self.url+"?"+form.data.urlencode())
```

Comment: This work: return redirect(self.url+'?'+urlencode(form.initial)), but there isn't a way like context to pass the data?